# Factoring a third degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I'm trying to find all solutions for $36x^3-127x+91=0$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So, I tried to factor this polynomial. It can be written in the following way:

$$
(ax^2+bx+c)\cdot(dx+e)\quad (a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

with

\begin{cases}
a \cdot d = 36 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2\\
a \cdot e + b \cdot d = 0\\
b \cdot e + c \cdot d = -127\\
c \cdot e = 91 = 7 \cdot 13
\end{cases}

How do I proceed from here? Should I guess possible values for $e$ ($±1,±7,±13,±91$) and see if it yields integer solutions for $a,b,c,d$? Or is there an easier method?

Comment: Do you know the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)? It's easier this way.

Comment: When you are asked to factor a cubic with integer coefficients, there will almost always be a rational root. Artificial, yes, but the process is too painful otherwise.

Comment: Do you see that $1$ is a remarkable root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$36x^3-127x+91=0$$

$$36x^3-36x-91x+91=0$$

$$36x(x^2-1)-91(x-1)=0$$

$$36x(x+1)(x-1)-91(x-1)=0$$

$$(x-1)(36x(x+1)-91)=0$$
$$(x-1)(36x^2+36x-91)=0$$

Comment: Oh wow, I missed the fact that $36 + 91 = 127$. Thank you.